# well known sieve?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sieve-theory

Incidentally I've shown the following fact.

Cancelling from the natural numbers $1$, the even integers, the integers of the form $n^2+2nk$, with $n>1$ odd and $k$ nonnegative, we obtain all (and only) the prime numbers.

Is it well known?

Comment: If you let $k$ vary in the inner loop, and $n$ in the outer, you have the classical Sieve of Eratosthenes, with a few easy (common) optimisations.

Answer (score 4):

Yes; your result is that every odd composite integer $N$ can be written in the form $N=n(n+2k)$ for some odd $n$ and $k \geq 0$. This follows immediately by considering the smallest divisor $n>1$ of $N$ and noting that $N/n$ is odd and not smaller than $n$. Of course, primes cannot be written in this form.